# C# / Mysql Quiz only 5 Questions

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a little Problem with my Code here, hope you can help me.

I'm trying to write a Quiz which displays the Question on the Form,
You can answer them by clicking one of the 5 Answerbutton.
The Questions are stored in a Mysql-Database.

In each game the Player has to answer 5 Questions,
and here Comes the Problem:

After 5 Questions it doesn't go to the Scorepage.

How can I fix this Problem?

Here is my attempt:

```
     public int richtig;

        int Counter = 0;
        string Loesung, AntwortA_value, AntwortB_value, AntwortC_value, AntwortD_value, AntwortE_value;

        string cmdText = "SELECT fragen,A,B,C,D,E,Loesungen from Fragen order by Rand() Limit 1;";
        string MyConString = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=quiz;UID=xxx;PASSWORD=xxx;";

        public Fragen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Questions();

        }

        private void Antworten_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Counter != 4)
            {
                Questions();
                Counter++;
            }
            else
            {

            }


        }

        private void Questions()
        {
            if (Counter != 5)
            {
                using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, connection);
                        connection.Open();
                        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            FragenTitel.Text = (reader[0].ToString());
                            AntwortA.Text = (reader[1].ToString());
                            AntwortB.Text = (reader[2].ToString());
                            AntwortC.Text = (reader[3].ToString());
                            AntwortD.Text = (reader[4].ToString());
                            AntwortE.Text = (reader[5].ToString());
                            Loesung = (reader[6].ToString());

                            AntwortA_value = (reader[1].ToString());
                            AntwortB_value = (reader[2].ToString());
                            AntwortC_value = (reader[3].ToString());
                            AntwortD_value = (reader[4].ToString());
                            AntwortE_value = (reader[5].ToString());
                        }
                        reader.Close();
                        connection.Close();

                        //lblError.Text = "Data Saved";
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("not entered");
                        //lblError.Text = ex.Message;
                    }

                }
            }
            else
            {
                Auswertungen Aw = new Auswertungen();
                Aw.Show();
            }

            Counter = richtig;
        }

        #region Antwortbuttons

        private void AntwortButtonA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (AntwortA_value == Loesung)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Richtig");
                Counter++;
                richtig++;
                Questions();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Falsch");
                Counter++;
                Questions();
            }
        }

        private void AntwortButtonB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (AntwortB_value == Loesung)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Richtig");
                Counter++;
                richtig++;
                Questions();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Falsch");
                Counter++;
                Questions();
            }
        }

        private void AntwortButtonC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (AntwortB_value == Loesung)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Richtig");
                Counter++;
                richtig++;
                Questions();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Falsch");
                Counter++;
                Questions();
            }
        }

        private void AntwortButtonD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (AntwortD_value == Loesung)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Richtig");
                Counter++;
                richtig++;
                Questions();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Falsch");
                Counter++;
                Questions();
            }
        }

        private void AntwortButtonE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (AntwortE_value == Loesung)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Richtig");
                Counter++;
                richtig++;
                Questions();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Falsch");
                Counter++;
                Questions();
            }
        #endregion


        }

        private void Score_uebername()
        {
          //  richtig = Auswertungen.Punktzahl;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What does t do instead? Have you tried using the debugger to confirm the test is working correctly?

Comment: Does it work after 5 or 6 right answers?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting more questions. I believe you havn't got the purpose of this platform right.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
 if (Counter != 4)
            {
                Questions();
                Counter++;
            }
            else
            {

            }
```

This peace of code never lets the counter to get to 5, meaning that this condition:

```
if (Counter != 5)
            {
               ....
            }
            else <--this condition is never met because Counter never gets to 5
            {
                Auswertungen Aw = new Auswertungen();
                Aw.Show();
            }
```

Once the user answers 5 Qs (counter=4) the program idles in an empty else block..

Comment: If the handles defined below Questions are used it would hit 5.